# Short story collection, crossovers between detectives, included a story about Agent Pendergrast and one involving a cursed artifact in a mausoleum

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think I listened to this as an audiobook in 2020 or 2021. I think the concept of the book was that they took two authors known for their detective fiction, and had them do a story where their characters met. The story that recently popped into my head involved a mystic investigator, and I think a more grounded one. There's an evil artifact in a mausoleum with a set of cultists after it. Another detective. I think the non-mystic one might have been Cotton Malone or Hieronymus Bosch because it led to me requesting some of their audiobooks, which only arrived months later. I don't remember who the mystic detective was

The other story that I remember some details of had [Agent Pendergast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloysius_Pendergast) waking up in a mental asylum, being told that his rather fantastical adventures were actually a long-held delusion with the psychiatrist pointing out to him how it being a psychotic delusion actually made more sense than his life.

And... that link got me the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book was *[FaceOff](https://www.fictiondb.com/title/gaslighted-slappy-the-ventriloquist-dummy-vs-aloys%7Erl-stine-douglas-preston-lincoln-child%7E1232150.htm)*, edited by David Baldacci.

> In an unprecedented collaboration, twenty-three of the world's bestselling and critically acclaimed thriller writers have paired their series characters -- such as Harry Bosch, Jack Reacher, and Lincoln Rhyme -- in an eleven-story anthology curated by the International Thriller Writers (ITW). All of the contributors to FaceOff are ITW members and the stories feature these dynamic duos:
>
> - Patrick Kenzie vs. Harry Bosch in “Red Eye,” by Dennis Lehane and Michael Connelly
> - John Rebus vs. Roy Grace in “In the Nick of Time,” by Ian Rankin and Peter James
> - Slappy the Ventriloquist Dummy vs. Aloysius Pendergast in “Gaslighted,” by R.L. Stine, Douglas Preston, and Lincoln Child
> - Malachai Samuels vs. D.D. Warren in “The Laughing Buddha,” by M.J. Rose and Lisa Gardner
> - Paul Madriani vs. Alexandra Cooper in “Surfing the Panther,” by Steve Martini and Linda Fairstein
> - Lincoln Rhyme vs. Lucas Davenport in “Rhymes With Prey,” by Jeffery Deaver and John Sandford
> - Michael Quinn vs. Repairman Jack in “Infernal Night,” by Heather Graham and F. Paul Wilson
> - Sean Reilly vs. Glen Garber in “Pit Stop,” by Raymond Khoury and Linwood Barclay
> - Wyatt Hunt vs. Joe Trona in “Silent Hunt,” by John Lescroart and T. Jefferson Parker
> - Cotton Malone vs. Gray Pierce in “The Devil's Bones,” by Steve Berry and James Rollins
> - Jack Reacher vs. Nick Heller in “Good and Valuable Consideration,” by Lee Child and Joseph Finder
>
> So sit back and prepare for a rollicking ride as your favorite characters go head-to-head with some worthy opponents in FaceOff -- it's a thrill-a-minute read.

I was remembering "The Devil's Bones" and "Gaslighted", the latter of which did have a cameo of Slappy the Ventriloquist Dummy as I recall it.

Comment: I want to read this!

Comment: I think there were two more volumes of FaceOff after this one?

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern: [*Matchup*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31939834-matchup) for one.

Comment: Did this contain SF or Fantasy elements?

Comment: @spencer Yes. I can't swear to the details of all the stories, but there are at least two involving magical artifacts.